# Vaadin consuming REST and performance

Tags: java, web-services, rest, vaadin

I have one question about how to construct app with vaadin and rest to gain good performace and scalability. I want to make rest api as a business layer and vaadin as ui for web. Ive made this decision cause my app will be also available as standalone version and on mobile os (ios and android). For me this idea is good if we are speaking about scalability but what about performance. Lets take about 5 thousand concurrent users for example.

I want to know general data about performance and will it be good for a lot of concurrent users. Only vaadin is hard to gain good performance with a lot of concurrent users (cause anyway almost all the code is running on the server). And if we also add rest api for any vaadin operation inside im scared that i will gain fatal combo.

Of course vaadin and rest api are located on the same server.

What do you think about it? Thanks a lot for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea, as Vaadin is a server side framework, so every action you do goes to the server, and from there on it has to make another rest service call to another server from where you have to get data and render it. I would rater suggest you to try some client side frameworks like `ExtJS, Jquery, Angular JS, GWT` etc... You render your UI on the client side using these frameworks and any action which requires data ops like fetching data or perform transactions you can make a rest service call to the server side. Using this approach you can avoid another redirection.

Now a days you the concept of `RWD` is getting popular, I think this would be a great choice for your use case. Build once deploy on any device :)

BTW, this is purely my opinion.

Comment: As @Patton pointed out probably you would step in some performance issues in your scenario. Anyway instead of droping Vaadin you could write your own widget to fetch those data client side...is not really that hard, and lose all Vaadin magic would be a shame ;-)